# Calligraphic Asian fonts in macOS

Tags: font

What fonts does macOS have that give major Asian scripts an artistic, calligraphic look, as if painted by a scholar with a brush? (As opposed to a formal, computer characters.)

I'll update the list as suggestions come. (Let me know if some important/beautiful script are left out.)

- China: *Xingkai*
- Japan: *Xingkai* (?)
- Korea: *Nanum*
- Burma
- Tibet
- Thailand
- Cambodia
- India

India has many scripts, so I'll leave it to a knowledgable person to suggest the major (or most artistic looking) scripts and corresponding calligraphic fonts for them.

Arabian scripts seem to look very hand-written by default, so suggestions are not necessary.

*(This question was initially posted about Chinese fonts, but I soon realised this question is relevant for other scripts too such as Japanese, Indian, Korean, etc. so I've generalised the question.)*

macOS has dozens of "greyed out" fonts in Font Book that can be downloaded on demand, but there's no guide to help you navigate these, except downloading all of them and trying them in turn.

I'm primarily looking for fonts that are available from Font Book. External font downloads only if macOS doesn't offer good enough scripts out of the box.

Some examples of the "artistic" look I'm looking for:

### Chinese

[image]

### Indian

(India doesn't have the same history of calligraphy as China, but in return there's no shortage of western yoga chicks who henna paint beautifully flowing Indian characters on their persons.)

[image]

PS! I don't know Asian scripts so I hope none of the pasted images contain insults of any kind.

Comment: Check out http://allchinesefont.com.

Answer (score 2):

On my El Capitan I have Xingkai SC:

[image]

[image]

This font can probably also be used for Japanese.

For Korean, MacOS has a calligraphic font called Nanum Brush.

For other Asian scripts, you would have to download something from a 3rd party.

Comment: "Xingkai" is in the list of downloadable greyed out fonts, and looks artistic and beautiful, provided the bold version of the font is selected. Probably because the bold font/stroke more resembles the use of a brush as opposed to a felt tip pen. I'll leave the question open for more good suggestions.